# mrz_parser depends on test_coverage >=0.1.1 which doesn't support null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, flutter-dependencies, pubspec.yaml

The current Dart SDK version is 3.2.6.

```
Because mrz_parser depends on test_coverage >=0.1.1 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.66.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety


You can try the following suggestion to make the pubspec resolve:
* Try using the Dart SDK version: 2.19.6. See https://dart.dev/get-dart.
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I try to run the project but facing this issue, although I have updated all the dependencies but still facing the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to include your `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: The latest version of mrz_parser is 2.0.0, make sure you're using that